# Term for misused diacritics

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms, diacritics

Is there a word which describes intentionally misusing or abusing diacritics, in contexts where they are neither needed nor appropriate, for purely stylistic reasons. For example:

> I submittéd my résumé to thé récruitér

Or perhaps the best example, the [metal umlaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut):

> `Spın̈al Tap`

Or in the most extreme case:

> `za͎͌l̰͝g̻̕o̬̅ ͎̂ẗ̥́ex̲̚t͓̃`

Comment: *Stultigraphia.*

Comment: Misspelt. They are a part od spelling after all.

Comment: Reminds me of when an editor I worked with referred to someone who abused commas as a [_comma comedian_](http://youtu.be/E5mwp264g-Q)

Comment: ¿Prétêntiousness?

Comment: @Gnawme Note, I really wasn't looking for a neologism. I was hoping to find a generally accepted term for this, though I suppose I'd accept a neologism if no such term exists.

Comment: Noted; I expanded my answer to include a non-neologism -- [cacography](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cacography). I think it's a great sounding word to describe your orthographic abuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd call it I'd call it [*diaerrhea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29). Or, if you want a less scatological alternative, *diaerrata*.

If *[orthography](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orthography?show=0&t=1377033734)* is "the art of writing words with the proper letters according to standard usage," including the correct diacritical marks, then its commonly accepted antonym, *[cacography](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cacography)*, would cover the kind of typographical abuse described. (Even if M-W rather prosaically defines *cacography* simply as "bad spelling.")

Comment: Actually, according the Wikipedia article on [cacography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacography), it sounds exactly like what I'm looking for.